# Grab specific element/value from a Div

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The element structure I'm trying to grab sort of looks like this

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="cost-box">
        <ins><span>$</span><price>10.00</price></ins>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the code below, I managed to grab the `cost-box` class, but I have no idea how to grab the `10.00` value under the `price` element.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.energyavenue.com/Lotus-LED/LBL-KDB-1'

response = requests.get(url).text

soup = bs(response, 'html.parser')

container = soup.find('div', class_="cost-box")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.energyavenue.com/Lotus-LED/LBL-KDB-1"

response = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(response, "html.parser")

container = soup.find("div", class_="cost-box")
price = container.price    # <-- get <price> tag from container
print(price.text)
```

Prints:

```
34.25
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! Will accept the answer in 5 mins! (wait time)

Answer (score 1):

Just find the `price` element.

```
price = container.find('price')
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the price at once with `soup.select_one` method (using CSS selectors):

```
price = soup.select_one('div.cost-box price').text
```